# I have faced a simple program of css the display flex issue actually i have created a div and under this i have 2 span i want to make them in flex box

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, mapping

I am using mapping in react and want to show the data in the flex box of css but it's not working please take a look at the code

[This is the code of react](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iDyn.png)
i am giving the display flex of header-data class

I am using mapping in react and want to show the data in the flex box of css but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

To the 'header-data' class, apply `display:flex`